# Two Air apps with the same applicationStorageDirectory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop

I have an AIR desktop app and I want to made another app that works like an admin panel. It must have the same applicationStorageDirectory to comunicate each other. It is posible? How? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't believe this is possible.

Alternatively you could create and access a common directory for both your apps in File.documentsDirectory. eg,

```
var common_file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("cibermans_apps/data.xml");
```

If you want to truly communicate between them live (not just edit common files) and both apps are running, you could use the [Local Connection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class.

Comment: Thanks! I will use this method (documentsDirectory) ... but, how do I do if I want to compile this two apps into a single air install exe?